# Cuando avanzo un video en el reproductor web este se reinicia y vuelve a comenzar

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework, nginx

Estoy montando un servicio con una API rest con django en un servidor con ubuntu server y nginx.

Mi problema es que cuando intento servir los datos de un archivo multimedia (.mp4, .webm, etc) y los reprodusco en el navegador solo puedo verlos en de forma lineal si avanzo o retrocedo el video este se reinicia, mientras que, en safari el reproductor no funciona. Probe con videos almacenados en otras plataformas y se repoducen correctamente por lo cual creo que algo me falta por implementar.

Comment: Has tenido en cuenta algún tipo de middleware para byte ranges?

Answer (score 0):

Es probable que estés utilizando FileResponse para servir tu vídeo pero el problema es que FileResponse no soporta Content-Range.

Existen varios tickets al respecto en las comunidades de Django pero hasta donde sé no hay ninguna solución ni se ha aceptado ningún PR. A pesar de esto hay varias formas de solucionarlo a través de middlewares, forzando a nginx a que haga los chunks, etc.

Por experiencia te recomiendo que utilices el paquete [django-ranged-fileresponse](https://pypi.org/project/django-ranged-fileresponse/). Tienes la documentación en [su repo](https://github.com/wearespindle/django-ranged-fileresponse), pero es bastante sencillo de utilizar:

```
from ranged_fileresponse import RangedFileResponse

def mi_video(request):
    filename = 'bizcochito_bailando.mp4'
    response = RangedFileResponse(request, open(filename, 'r'), content_type='video/mp4')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % filename
    return response
```